# If a question is put "on hold" but I have answered, should I remove the answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, on-hold

**Context:**

You will notice on the topic [What is Facebook's privacy policy regarding photos?](https://superuser.com/questions/1238994/what-is-facebooks-privacy-policy-regarding-photos/1238996#1238996) that it has been put [on hold]. However it was done *after* I had posted an answer.

**Question:**

At the time, I didn't realize that it was off-topic. However, now that I realize it is in the incorrect place, rather than receiving multiple down votes for answering, should I delete the answer?

Comment: You should make an effort NOT to answer questions that are not on topic here at Superuser.  If you want to flag them for migration to the correct website then you should do that.

Comment: And in the case that you didn't realize until after? Would it be better for the answer to be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eh. I'd rather people *not* answer them, but there's no real need to delete it at this point. The question and answer will be deleted at some point in the future anyway.

Now, if you're worried about downvotes, sure, but the correct thing is not to correct, it is to do the right thing to start with.

Comment: The answer has been deleted by the owner, and if no miracle occurs in step 3, the question is likely to be deleted as downvoted abandoned somewhat soonish.